# Login with Devise - Log in the account when click in the link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a panel with many registered users. I want a link for each user, when I click on the link, I log in that account, without the password.
As the resellers systems do. The reseller admin log in the account of the customer account (Parallels Plesk do it).

All the users were registered with Devise.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. it's possible. just call the same method you call to create a session for the user. the link would be something like (you'll need to make sure the path agrees with the one you're using):

```
<a href="/users/sign_in_as_user/<%= user['user_id'] %>" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Sign In</a>
```

with something like this in the controller:

```
def sign_in_as_user
  if current_user.admin?
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    sign_in(user)
    redirect_to '/wherever'
  else
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry the delay, I forgot the feedback. Your solution works perfectly, thanks! I added only one more param. A secure hash, with a complex combination with the user data. With this, people who had try the Id in this URL do not get to access, because need more info

Comment: Great! Glad it helped.